# main() prints out values of multidimensional array differently from paint()

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, paint, program-entry-point

I'm trying to use paint() to draw rectangles to the screen.  If there is a 1 in my array at a location, then on the screen it will be a blue rectangle.  If there is a 0 in my array at a location, then on the screen it will be a black rectangle.  I create this array by accessing a .bmp file and reading the lines.  These lines (essentially Strings) are then turned into character arrays with .toCharArray() which are turned into integer arrays.  So this finalized array is filled with 1 and 0 integers.  I then go into paint(), call the function getBits() which creates the array, and store it in numArray, which is a 2D array.  For debugging purposes, I called getBits() in main() and printed out the array, which came out to:

```
1000000000
1101000000
1111000000
0000000000
1001000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

This is the correct output of the array if it were in an x-y coordinate system. ^

However, when I call getBits() in paint() and store it in numArray then proceed to execute my conditionals to check whether it's a 1 or a 0, it always chooses 0.  It seems like there's an error of some sorts and everything is somehow changed to 0.  But I know that the array contains 1s because of the debugging in main() which printed out the 1s and 0s in the above sample output.

```
public class bitmaps extends JApplet{
public void init(int[][] numArray){
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
}

//This function reads from a bitmap file and stores the characters (0s and 1s) into arrayLists
public static int[][] getBits(){
    File bitmap;
    Scanner reader;
    int[][] numArray = new int[20][10];

    try{
        bitmap = new File("C:/Users/kingsman142/Desktop/Projects/bitmap.bmp");
        reader = new Scanner(bitmap);

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        String readStrings = "";

        //While there is more stuff in the file
        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            readStrings = reader.nextLine();

            //Run through each line, grab strings, turn into char arrays, turn those into integers and add them to numArray
            for(column = 0; column < readStrings.toCharArray().length; column++){
                numArray[row][column] = Character.getNumericValue(readStrings.toCharArray()[column]);
            }

            //Assign all other values that haven't been assigned yet to 0
            for(column = column; column < 10; column++){
                numArray[row][column] = 0;
            }
            row++;
        }

        reader.close();
    } catch(Exception e){

    }

    //return all of the 1s and 0s
    return numArray;
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);

    int[][] numArray = getBits();

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;

    for(row = 0; row < 20; row++){
        for(column = 0; column < 10; column++){
            //If it's a 0, make it a blue rectangle
            //If it's a 1, make it a black rectangle
            //Else, make it a yellow rectangle (never had this problem yet)
            if(numArray[row][column] == 1){
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
            } else if(numArray[row][column] == 0){
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            } else{
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            }

            //Draw the rectangle
            g.fillRect(column*10, row*10, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] numArray = getBits();

    //Print out the array (output of this is in the question)
    for(int row = 0; row < 20; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < 10; column++){
            System.out.print(String.valueOf(numArray[row][column]) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that I can fix this IF I put numArray in global scope and initialize every single position myself.  The problem is that I don't want to do that for my program because I want to use any bitmap.

This is what my output should look like and what it actually looks like:

[[image: expected output]]

So my question is... why does my main() function see numArray differently than paint() does? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Applets don't run a main method. If I were you, I'd remove that method and instead concentrate on the `init()` method. Read the bits **once** in `init()` and not in paint. Also, you should never override the paint method nor should you draw directly in the applet, but rather override the paintComponent method of a JPanel that is displayed in the applet.

Comment: What do you mean they don't run a main method?  I'm only using main() for debugging, not actually affecting the applet.

Comment: OK, but still call the `getBits()` once in init. And again, don't paint in the applet itself. By calling a relatively slow method in paint, you could be completely hamstringing the method, preventing it from painting. Also, you never call a super painting method -- it looks like you are Swing graphics tutorial deficient and will want to fix this.

Comment: Also, why is your catch block empty -- that's asking for disaster. Also, you should not be reading in Files but resources.... too many issues here...

Comment: My guess is your have issues reading the file from an applet context, but you are ignoring any exception which might be getting generated.  Try adding `e.printStackTrace()` in side the `catch` clause and see if anything is printed to the console.  Otherwise your code does what you seem to be wanting it to do

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I added getBits() to init and it did nothing.  What do you mean by "don't paint in the applet itself"?  Where else am I supposed to paint?  And as I said earlier, the paint method works perfectly fine if I initialize the array in global scope.  It only screws up when it's called from the function.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Nothing is printed to the console.  And you're right, the function does exactly what I want it to do, but when I call it in paint(), the entire array just defaults to a bunch of 0s, which is not what is supposed to happen.

Comment: You code runs fine, it paints the contents of the bmp file (I created at least) as expected, but I suspect that if you try to run this from a applet context (outside of the applet viewer), the security manager will kick in and prevent you from reading the file.  Yet another reason why we tend to recommend against using applets.  You're ignoring the exception which may provide you with the information you need to further diagnose your issue

Comment: @Bob Your code works fine me, prints a nice series of blue blobs as defined by the file contents.  You're going to need to start placing diagnostics into your code (`System.out.println`) to trace the execution progress and print your variables.  You should also take the time to learn how to set a break point in your IDE and debug your code

Comment: @MadProgrammer But it doesn't throw any exception, you can CLEARLY see that from the main() function because it prints out everything perfectly every time i compile the program.  The only problem is when I call getBits() from paint(), which is where everything value is turned into a 0.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah I have a bunch of debugging steps, like System.out.println in my code, but I didn't include that in this question because it might confuse people or they might wonder why they're there.

Comment: @Bob `main` runs in a different context to your `applet`, which runs within a tighter security sand box.  When I create a version of the `bitmap.bmp` of my own, your paint code runs just fine

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just tested it on my laptop and it doesn't work.  Can you screenshot your output?  I have no idea how it would run perfectly on your computer with the blue blobs because I've tested it on 2 machines and it won't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I provide my own `bitmap.bmp` file, the code seems to print just fine

[image: Display]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class bitmaps extends JApplet {

    public void init(int[][] numArray) {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    }

//This function reads from a bitmap file and stores the characters (0s and 1s) into arrayLists
    public static int[][] getBits() {
        File bitmap;
        Scanner reader;
        int[][] numArray = new int[20][10];

        try {
            bitmap = new File("bitmap.bmp");
            reader = new Scanner(bitmap);

            int row = 0;
            int column = 0;

            String readStrings = "";

            //While there is more stuff in the file
            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                readStrings = reader.nextLine();

                //Run through each line, grab strings, turn into char arrays, turn those into integers and add them to numArray
                for (column = 0; column < readStrings.toCharArray().length; column++) {
                    numArray[row][column] = Character.getNumericValue(readStrings.toCharArray()[column]);
                }

                //Assign all other values that haven't been assigned yet to 0
                for (column = column; column < 10; column++) {
                    numArray[row][column] = 0;
                }
                row++;
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //return all of the 1s and 0s
        return numArray;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        int[][] numArray = getBits();

        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        for (row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
                //If it's a 0, make it a blue rectangle
                //If it's a 1, make it a black rectangle
                //Else, make it a yellow rectangle (never had this problem yet)
                if (numArray[row][column] == 1) {
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                } else if (numArray[row][column] == 0) {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                }

                //Draw the rectangle
                g.fillRect(column * 10, row * 10, 10, 10);
            }
        }
    }

//  public static void main(String[] args) {
//      int[][] numArray = getBits();
//
//      //Print out the array (output of this is in the question)
//      for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
//          for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
//              System.out.print(String.valueOf(numArray[row][column]) + " ");
//          }
//          System.out.println("");
//      }
//  }
}
```

There are a bunch of possibilities, but because you're ignoring the `Exception`, it's hard to know which ones you've run up against

You should know that applets run in a very tight security sandbox, so your applet may not even be able to read the file at all

And my test file...

```
0000000000
1111111111
1010101010
0101010101
1100110011
0000000000
1111111111
1010101010
0101010101
1100110011
0000000000
1111111111
1010101010
0101010101
1100110011
0000000000
1111111111
1010101010
0101010101
1100110011
```

Comment: Where did you get that applet viewer from?  I've just been using an html file and inserting my applet into that.

Comment: `appletview.exe` is in the JDK/bin directory.  Netbeans will execute it by default, but also auto generates the HTML

Comment: Sorry to bother you about this, but it might be the solution to my problem.  Can I run my program using the appletviewer.exe in the command prompt? If so, how?

Comment: Try `appletviewer -?` from the command line for a list of options

Comment: Thank you so much @MadProgrammer!  It was the browser all along.  Apparently applets aren't supported by browsers anymore?  So when I was using IE to run my program, it wouldn't do what I wanted it to do.  Sorry for bugging you about this simple thing, but I appreciate your quick, fast, and helpful information a lot.

Comment: Applets have always run in a tight security sand box, having the ability to read/write to the local drive has always been one of the restrictions.  Although now days, both Applets and Flash are falling out of favor by the browser developers in favor of HTML 5 and in some cases are been actively blocked altogether.  Generally speaking, we discourage there use because they are a pain to get running when you're just learning and it's easier to use a `JFrame` as the top level container to get things working (if you place the core of your logic in something like a `JPanel`)